# How to default values to array when user input enter key using cin method?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing a code where I am asking user to assign value to an array and where user press enter key I want to assign a default value to array elements. Any idea how to proceed with this ?

I have tried using cin.get() method but it is not working. Here is my code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter array size: ";
    cin >> n;

    double y[n];
   
    string input;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter Initial Velocity ( Default Value 0 ) : " ;
        y[i] = cin.get();
        if (input=="")
        {
            y[i]=0.0;
        }
        else
        {
            y[i]=stod(input);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `input` will always be an empty string since nothing ever changes it so the array value will always be overwritten with 0.

Comment: `y[i] = cin.get();` -> `std::getline(std::cin);`?

Comment: Worse, the compilers that do allow arrays of variable length expect you to use them carefully.  With `cin >> n;`, the user is allowed to control the size of the array and since the user's input is not checked or bound in any meaningful way, they could enter a large value and run the program out of Automatic Storage. Not much fun debugging the effects of that. They could input a zero or a negative number, and that won't be much fun to debug, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to change minimal things to make your code work as you've expected. Bunch of stuff can be improved, array creation ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)), not including useless files, reducing the scope of local variables, also don't use `using namespace std` - [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

```cpp
#include <math.h> //useless

#include <cmath> //useless
#include <iostream>
//#include <string> some compilers may require adding this


using namespace std; //bad practice

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter array size: ";
    cin >> n;

    double y[n]; //not a great way to create an array, fix this
    cin.ignore();

    //can be moved inside the loop
    string input;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << "Enter Initial Velocity ( Default Value 0 ) : ";
        getline(cin, input);
        if (input == "") {
            y[i] = 0.0;
        } else {
            y[i] = stod(input);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i > 0) cout << ' ';
        cout << y[i];
    }

    cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: FYI, the `using namespace std;` should be removed also.

Comment: The code is missing `#include <string>`.

Comment: Always include what you use. `#include <string>` is not optional. Just because another header pulls it in today it may not tomorrow, and your code breaks, or you switch to another compiler and your code breaks.

Comment: @SandroJ Can you explain  "double y[n]; //not a great way to create an array, fix this" why this is not a great way ?

Comment: @ThickThighs Updated the answer with the link to the thread explaining that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
  {
  cout << "Press the ENTER key";
  if (cin.get() == '\n')
    cout << "Good job.\n";
  else
    cout << "I meant ONLY the ENTER key... Oh well.\n";
  return 0;
  }
```